# Resizing tableview's first visible section header height

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

I created a `UITableView` that contains custom section header views. Now, I want it to display a bit more data on the uppermost current visible section. I plan to use the event `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating` to update the section headers. Currently, the problem is that I cannot set the section header height for a specific section number.

I did try using `heightForHeaderInSection` beforehand, but the app just crashes with the following output:

`'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'`

I was using the code:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (tableView == self.tableView)
    {
        NSArray *visibleCells = [self.tableView visibleCells];
        NSMutableArray *visibleSections = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        for (NSInteger index = 0; index < [visibleCells count]; index++)
        {
            UITableViewCell *currentCell = [visibleCells objectAtIndex:index];
            NSIndexPath *currentPath = (NSIndexPath *)[self.tableView indexPathForCell:currentCell];
            if (![visibleSections containsObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:currentPath.section]])
            {
                [visibleSections addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:currentPath.section]];
                NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)[visibleSections count]]);
                [visibleSections sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:nil ascending:YES]]];
            }
        }
        if (visibleSections == nil)
        {
            return 42.0;
        }
        else if ([[visibleSections objectAtIndex:0] integerValue] == section)
        {
            return 58.0;
        }
        else
        {
            return 42.0;
        }
    }
}
```

I couldn't quite work out what went wrong in my `heightForHeaderInSection` method, but I knew it had something to do with the `NSMutableArray`, visibleSections.

Any hints or answers as to how I can go about changing the height for a specific section header view outside of `heightForHeaderInSection` and/or how I can fix my code above would be really helpful.

**Edit:**

Just to make the solution to my crashing problem a bit clearer, `if (visibleSections == nil)` should not be used in place of `if ([visibleSections count] < 1)` or `if ([visibleSections count] == 0)`.

Comment: What does you log of [visibleSection count] show?

Comment: @rdelmar It just edited the log to be after line 6, and it outputs zero. I'm guessing that the code is launched even when content haven't even displayed by the app.

Comment: @rdelmar But I'm confused as to why it even outputs the error when it won't even be used if its empty.

Comment: BTW, you shouldn't use stringWithFormat in a log statement that way -- NSLog has its own format string. Should just be: NSLog(@"%ld",[visibleSections count]);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so it turns out this is a harder problem than it first seems. The best I have come up with so far is

- Don't treat the header that is for the top section any different and populate them all with the extra data.
- You can show and hide different parts by being clever with positioning the "additional" items so that they will be outside of the parent view's bounds when it is smaller and making the parent view `clipToBounds`.
- Failing that you can make a custom `UIView` subclass and do some manipulation in `layoutSubviews`

The end implementation I was settling on was this

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
  NSArray *indexPaths = [self.tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows];
  self.topSection = [indexPaths count] ? [indexPaths[0] section] : -1;
  if (indexPaths.count > 1) {
    self.topSection = [indexPaths[1] section];
  }

  [self.tableView beginUpdates];
  [self.tableView endUpdates];
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section;
{
  if (section <= self.topSection) {
    return 60;
  } else {
    return 20;
  }
}
```

It's by no means perfect but it looked semi reasonable and could be tweaked.

Things to note:

- You may need to assess if there is too much work going on in `scrollViewDidScroll:` but it didn't appear to cause any lag for me (I've not really tested properly)
- I set the top section using the second `indexPath` if available as it looked slightly more pleasing/less clunky
- I use `section <= self.topSection` because the header's before are all of screen so there is no point in reducing the size of them which causes really clunky animation.

So after trying this you may need to dig deeper or want to rethink your design a little

Comment: This would work very well, but I'm using translucent gradients for my section header, which extends outside of the header's view. I guess I'll have to tweak my design a little bit.

Comment: Well you can make the headerView a custom subclass and then you should be able to find a suitable point to ask the view to redraw its gradient

Answer (score 1):

I think you could also do it like this, if you want the first section header to be taller when the table first appears (topSection is an NSInteger property):

```
-(void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    self.topSection = ((NSIndexPath *)[self.tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows][0]).section;
    [self.tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:self.topSection] withRowAnimation:NO];
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

        if (self.topSection == section)
        {
            return 58.0;
        }
        else
        {
            return 42.0;
        }
}
```

Comment: +1 but would it be better to have the `topSection` query in the `tableView:heightForHeaderInSection:` method?

Comment: @Paul.s, I tried that first, and that crashes. It seems to go into an infinite loop. Not sure why.

Comment: This works excellent. I've marked this as the answer. **Edit:** I've also changed the title to be more accurate.

Comment: One slight amendment - if the tableview is empty and you scroll this will crash you still need a guard perhaps something like `NSArray *indexPaths = [self.tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows];
  self.topSection = [indexPaths count] ? [indexPaths[0] section] : -1;`

Comment: It updates fine, but it makes my header view quickly fades in and out when updating though.

Comment: Can you describe a bit better whats happening?

Comment: @Paul.s The section header and the cells in the section that are reloaded fades out and in, in a split second to update the position of the cells. This gives the tableview quite an unpleasant look, and a slightly confusing experience. Instead of pushing down the cells, it just fades out and into the new position.

Comment: You should be able to replace the call to `[self.tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:self.topSection] withRowAnimation:NO];` with the `[self.tableView beginUpdates]; [self.tableView endUpdates];` calls

Comment: @Paul.s It does the pushing nicely now, but it doesn't draw in the new section header view. I tried adding `[self.tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:topSection] withRowAnimation:NO];` after the calls you suggested, but it gives a weird glitch that duplicates section headers.

Comment: What do you mean by `it doesn't draw in the new section header view`?

Comment: @Paul.s I coded `- (UIView *)tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:` such that it will display more data on the section header when the height for the section header is 58.0, but using `[self.tableView beginUpdates]; [self.tableView endUpdates];` calls do not make the section header view update.

Comment: @Jay, did you try using reloadData instead of reloadSections? It's a bit brute force, but you don't get the funny glitch, and I would think it would update your header view.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly refer to the arrays first object by calling objectAtIndex:0, you gotta stay defensive so change this:

```
else if ([[visibleSections objectAtIndex:0] integerValue] == section)
    {
        return 58.0;
    }
```

To

```
else if([visibleSections count]>0)
    {
      if ([[visibleSections objectAtIndex:0] integerValue] == section)
        {
           return 58.0;
        }
     }
```

Comment: Thanks, this solves the crashing problem, but it is still not performing the way I want it to. I'll investigate into that and post another question if I have to.

Btw, I just used `if ([visibleSections count] < 1)` to avoid writing more lines.

Comment: Why is the accepted answer an answer that doesn't actually compile? - probably a side effect of the poor formatting used... There is an unnecessary `else` inside the `if` block

Comment: @Paul.s Sorry it was a typo.

Answer (score -1):

Try changing this line:

```
NSMutableArray *visibleSections = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]
```

to:

```
NSMutableArray *visibleSections = [NSMutableArray array];
```

Which initializes the array.

Comment: Those two statements are essentially equivalent.

Comment: *Both statements initialize the array.* The only difference is that the first method returns a (+1) retained object and the second not. With ARC, you will not notice the difference at all.